# wrong loop iterations with nested db queries in ios .while Loop not running proper number of times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

The code runs fine if the commented portion remains commented.The while loop should run two times and it does cause there are only two rows in threads table.However,if i uncomment the commented code the while loop runs only one time which is the wrong output

```
sql = "select thread_id,timestamp from threads";

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSString* abc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];
            NSString* def = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            NSLog(@"%@",abc);
            NSLog(@"%@",def);
            NSString* threadid = abc;
            NSString *sql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from my where t_id=\"%@\"",threadid];

**Commented code begin**               
            /* sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);

            sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database);
                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql2 UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                int a = sqlite3_data_count(selectstmt2);
                NSLog(@"%d",a);

                    if (a==1) {

                    sql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select timestamp from my where t_id=\"%@\"",threadid];
                        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql2 UTF8String], -1, &selectstmt2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                            NSString* abc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt2, 0)];
                            NSLog(@"%@",abc);
                            }
                        }  
                    } 

                    if(a==0) {

                    char* error;
                    sql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into my(t_id,time) values(\"%@\",\"%@\")",threadid,@"0"];

                    int i = sqlite3_exec(database, [sql2 UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error) ;
                    NSLog(@"inserted");
                    sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
                    }
              }*/

**Commented code end**

**program end**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are finalizing the prepared statement, inside the same loop you are processing it in. Not surprisingly, the next time you attempt to use the statement, it fails. Note that, each of the calls you make to the statement, after it is has been finalized, returns an error code that you can check before proceeding with additional logic.